# What is the full name of this bicycle? Thank you!

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: What is the full name of this bicycle? Thank you!]
Can anyone help me find the full name of this bike? i would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt

Comment: That seat is far too high - the rider it was sized for needs a bigger frame.  At least check the minimum insert line on the seat post is down inside  the frame.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a Cervélo RS (from some time around 2008) with an aftermarket Easton EC90 fork and DT Swiss wheelset fitted.

You can find a review of the bike from when it was released [here](http://www.cyclingweekly.co.uk/news/product-news/first-ride-cervelo-rs-96423).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to find the bike by the serial number?  Can you plese tell me what is the price of a new one like this?

Comment: And herein lies the reason for the question...

Comment: Also has mechanical Dura Ace groupset? But not sure of series.

http://www.cyclingweekly.co.uk/news/product-news/first-ride-cervelo-rs-96423

According to the link above - the frame was £1600. It won't be difficult to figure out a new for old price from that.

Comment: I'm curious how this bike was procured... Not many people sell with their quadlock still attached to the stem!

Comment: Yes, I'd run the serial number through BikeIndex or your local police to make sure it wasn't stolen. This is good advice for any used bike.